# Optimizing AWS Lambda invocations based on input data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an API endpoint with lambda. Business logic in this lambda needs very big JSON file that will be used as config, so it is provided as link to S3 from where it's downloaded. Assuming that:

- Logic related to parsing and processing this JSON takes a long time
- This lambda is invoked very often with different JSON files (it's dynamic as it comes from user config generated in saas-like website), but a lot of these invocations will use the same json (e.g one user is generating a lot of requests)

I'm wondering if there is a solution where I could balance these requests in a way that if some lambda with json "xxx" is already hot, I could reuse it in order to avoid parsing and processing this json data again. Or maybe there is possibility to cache and share some data (already parsed and processed json) between lambdas?
Project is on early stage so architecture/stack change is still possible at this moment.

Comment: If you are using API gateway along with aws lambda then you can try enabling API caching or another approach I can suggest is to store parsed JSON file into s3 bucket with unique file name (i.e user_name.json) and try to fetch it from s3 before process it again . Hope it helps Thanks!

Comment: @SmitParmar I can't use API caching cause this json is not only input data, so usually response won't be the same.

As for storing it and fetching from S3. That's what I'm doing right now